Как загрейдить миграции во Flask
Суть такая: хочу при создании новой модели автоматически вносить записи в БД в таблицы content_types и permissions, таким образом хочу сделать, как минимум, права на уровне моделей, хочется хотя бы базовые CRUD-права. Вообще возможно ли такое в рамках flask и SQLAlchemy сделать? Если реально - прошу с этим помочь.
